# Cast string to double

Tags: vb.net

Probably very simple question but still trying to figure it out. I got many input doubles provided as strings in this format:

```
0.99
0.456
etc..
```

On my dev system when I convert it like:

```
CDbl(0.456)
```

It's fine, however on production I get `SystemInvalidCastException.`

I am not sure but I bet its about different systems symbols like dots or commas.

Is there any way to be independent from system configuration and trade my input strings to be correctly recognized as double?

I tried with this approach and seems it's working. Is this right way to do?

```
Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the right way you're going.

The problem is indeed culture related. If you do not specifiy any culture it will default to the system's culture which will most likely be the reason for the code to work on one system but not on the other.

By specifying the invariant culture you ensure that the systems culture has no effect anymore on the casting.